# Setting checkbox value in angular after initialization

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, angular2-template, angular2-directives

So I have this checkbox, I have binded ngModel to it and based on the ngModel it properly sets the checkbox as checked or unchecked.

The problem is, if I change the checkbox, I check for some conditions and based on some that condition I make the ngModel binded to it false again, so technically it should go back to unchecked state if it was checked and the condition satisfied, but it's not. Although my ngModel shows a value of false.

Even tried with the [checked] attribute, but it's also not working.

Any inputs are highly appreciated

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" [checked]="isChecked" (ngModelChange)="onChange('statusPush',$event)">
```

in Component

```
if(someCondition) {
this.isChecked = false
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  But I'm guessing this might help you --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450254/how-to-set-checkbox-ng-checked-from-server-data-using-angularjs-and-save-the-che/54450255#54450255 if what described there is what you intended to do

Comment: Chill bro, it's been over a year!

Comment: I'm just trying to help to solve your cold case. I ain't no bro, either. LOL!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, just add a time out function before making the value of `isChecked` true or false in your onChange function

```
if(someCondition) {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.isChecked = false
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.